# How to display PDF from URL For different language in android

Tags: android, pdf

I am making an app in which I am displaying a PDF file from url on `WebView` by appending Google Doc url i.e;

```
String pdf_url = "my pdf url";
webView.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url="+pdf_url);
```

its displaying perfect but my app is in Swedish Language and its a requirement of the app that every word must be display in Swedish Language. The problem is when pdf file is shown its showing `copy right and some words by Google` in English language. Is there a way to convert these words in Swedish? may be the Google Doc url `(https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=)` has the option to set language value. I can't figure this one out and stuck here. Any type of help would be appreciated.

The current output is shown below in the picture for better understanding

[image]

Answer (score 0):

can you try to add "se" or "SE" just before the end of the url : exemple:

```
www.myUrl.html ===> www.myUrl.se.html
www.myUrl.pdf ===> www.myUrl.se.pdf
```

Comment: My PDF Url is comming from web service, its not static, by putting "SE" or "se" just before the end of url will change the original url and Google doc will never find that pdf file.